# CGAL output parametrized mesh

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

I am currently using CGAL to compute a parametrization from a closed mesh.
This is the example I am following:
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_parameterization/Surface_mesh_parameterization_2seam_Polyhedron_3_8cpp-example.html

Is there any way to output the 3D mesh with the uv coordinates/texture map with CGAL?
For instance, over an obj file or a ply.

Seems such a simple thing but I can't quite find a function for it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

CGAL does not currently have features to handle texture. However, handling UV properties is doable. The simplest way to output properties to a file is to:

- use [`CGAL::Surface_mesh`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/index.html) to store your mesh
- use simple properties (double, int, etc.) to store U V info
- use [`CGAL::write_ply()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/group__PkgSurface__mesh.html#ga77bbb79d449c981895eedb6c3c23bd14) to write your file

For example, if I run this piece of code:

```cpp
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh/IO.h>

using Kernel = CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>;
using Point_3 = Kernel::Point_3;
using Mesh = CGAL::Surface_mesh<Point_3>;
using Vertex_index = Mesh::Vertex_index;
using Halfedge_index = Mesh::Halfedge_index;
using Edge_index = Mesh::Edge_index;

int main()
{
  Mesh mesh;

  Mesh::Property_map<Edge_index, double> u_map
    = mesh.add_property_map<Edge_index, double>("U").first;
  Mesh::Property_map<Edge_index, double> v_map
    = mesh.add_property_map<Edge_index, double>("V").first;

  Vertex_index v0 = mesh.add_vertex(Point_3(0,0,0));
  Vertex_index v1 = mesh.add_vertex(Point_3(0,0,1));
  Halfedge_index hi = mesh.add_edge (v0, v1);
  Edge_index ei = mesh.edge(hi);

  u_map[ei] = 0.2;
  v_map[ei] = 0.8;

  std::ofstream ofile ("out.ply");
  CGAL::write_ply (ofile, mesh);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get the following output PLY file which does store the UV property on the edge:

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment Generated by the CGAL library
element vertex 2
property double x
property double y
property double z
element face 0
property list uchar int vertex_indices
element edge 1
property int v0
property int v1
property double U
property double V
end_header
0 0 0 
0 0 1 
1 0 0.2 0.8
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to do the same with a Seam_mesh? Or convert it (parametrization included) to a Surface_mesh?

For example, based on https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_parameterization/Surface_mesh_parameterization_2seam_Polyhedron_3_8cpp-example.html how can I output a ply (containing the uv coords) from the Seam_mesh object?